# Angular Cli: Chart with horizontal separate lines

Tags: angular, charts, c3.js

To build this graph I use `C3.js` library. But she is not completely satisfied me.

The problem is that the lines of the same color have 2 different coordinates for one Axis - and i have to avoid default functions.

Can anyone recommend a library that could build such a chart using default methods?

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://c3js.org/samples/simple_xy.html)  what you're using? Why not use d3.js?

Comment: @HarishVangavolu Yes, i use this lib

Comment: it was easier for me than to build a graph via d3, and I did not see examples of how to do something similar in d3

Comment: Maybe [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point) will be easier and cleaner for you. Here's an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js) by [@domiSchenk](https://stackblitz.com/@domiSchenk) of its use in Angular.